# sizeof operator and multidimensional table

Tags: c++, sizeof

I've got a problem because i dont know how sizeof operator works. Could anyone tell me why it gives me 4 in below code?

```
int tab[2] = {1, 5};
int *filePathTab[1] = {NULL};
filePathTab[0] = tab;
cout << sizeof(filePathTab[0]);
```

Comment: `filePathTab[0]` is `int*`.

Comment: Here's a hint: what does `sizeof(&tab[0])` give you?

Comment: so how then can i use it properly? so that it gives me 8?

Comment: You need a 64-bit machine (or compilation) for it to give you 8.  The size of a pointer will always be the size of the pointer, regardless of what the pointer points at.

Comment: @Babbaddo: You cannot use `sizeof` to get the size of `tab` by applying `sizeof` to any expression based on `filePathTab` because the `filePathTab` object does not know anything about the size of `tab`. The `filePathTab` object is only an array of pointers. A pointer tells you only where something starts; it does not tell you how big it is. So the pointers in `filePathTab` do not have any information about the size of things they point to. To get the size of `tab`, you must use `sizeof tab` or maintain its size yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filePathTab[0]` has a `int *` as its element.  The `sizeof` an `int *` on your machine is 4 bytes.  If you want to know the `sizeof` what the `int *` is pointing to, an `int`, you have to dereference the pointer:

```
cout << sizeof(*filePathTab[0]);
```

It may turn out that the `sizeof` an `int` on your machine is also 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Because `filePathTab[0]` is of type `int*` (`filePathTab` is an array of pointers, you are considering the zeroth element) and the size of a pointer to `int` on your machine happens to be 4 *bytes*.

Answer (score 2):

Sizeof gives you the size of the argument in bytes. Since pointers to int are 4 bytes long (this depends on the system), the output of sizeof is 4.